# Cas de liaisons consécutives (liaisons avec « mais »)

Tags: liaisons

Dans le texte suivant, la possibilité de faire deux liaisons consécutives (caractères gras ajoutés) me pose un problème.

> Il n’était pas possible que dans ces yeux durs et plats une douceur s’installât soudain. **Mais ils étaient** devenus plus brumeux, ils avaient perdu leur pureté de métal. (Extrait de *La Peste* d'Albert Camus)

La liaison est nécessaire entre « ils » et « étaient » ;

> [liaisons obligatoires](http://research.jyu.fi/phonfr/20a.html#1)
> en /z/ et /n/ avec les formes faibles des pronoms personnels sujet
> nous, vous, ils, elles, on
> nous‿y penserons, elles‿écoutent, on‿y va,

Entre « mais » et « ils (il, elle,…) » il faudrait une liaison dans la langue soignée.

- Mais il arrive que… - Mais elle n'était pas… - Mais ils ne pouvaient…

> [liaison après **mais**](http://research.jyu.fi/phonfr/20a.html#3)
> La liaison (en /z/) après **mais** est relativement fréquente dans la pro­non­cia­tion soignée, mais elle est plutôt aléatoire. Dans la langue parlée courante, on ne la fait pas (sauf dans le groupe figé **mais encore**) :
>
> - Mais‿il est impossible de prédire quand on fait la liaison après mais.
> - On est // allés faire du shopping, mais // on a rien // acheté. (pro­non­cia­tion courante).

Lorsque les deux liaisons sont combinées elles semblent être en trop, et donne une impression de zézaiement, tout au moins en ce qui me concerne ; donc, selon le principe général qui veut que la liaison avec « mais » soit aléatoire, je pense qu'il est du moins plus « clair » de ne pas faire cette liaison dans une prononciation soignée. Seulement, ce n'est que mon impression, et des certitudes concernant cette question seraient préférables.

Existe-t-il un principe concernant les liaisons consécutives ?
Dans le cas relevé dans le texte de Camus ci-dessus, doit-on considérer comme correct de faire les deux liaisons,  de ne faire que la liaison obligatoire, ou les deux ?

Comment: Dans _On est // allés faire du shopping, mais // on a rien // acheté_, si // indique "pas de liaison", l'exemple est contestable. On peut très bien dire cette phrase avec les trois liasons, couramment. Ne pas faire ces liaisons sonne étrange plus que de les faire.

Comment: @Frank D'accord sur ce point, j'en fais normalement deux : « On estallés faire du shopping, mais // on a rienacheté, ».

Comment: Je devrais peut-être vous expliquer ce que « zézaiement » signifie, et vous comprendriez alors de quel problème il s'agit. On attendra pour mieux savoir que d'autres utilisateurs formulent un avis.

Comment: Le Robert indique [les liaisons facultatives et les liaisons obligatoires](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/liaisons-et-enchainements). la première liaison (Mais//ils) étant facultative, on peut l'omettre en fonction de la [prosodie](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/prosodie) souhaitée (ou pour éviter l'effet de zézaiement).

Comment: @Graffito Pourquoi ne pas faire une réponse de ces informations  ? Ce serait plus facile à lire.

Comment: It seems to me that the downvotes on this question may be vindictive and personally motivated. While a user's behaviour may be problematic, downvoting the question isn't the best way to address it. Use flags on the sources of the problem, such as comments.

Answer (score 2):

Il y a quelques règles en ce qui concerne les liaisons, elles ont [déjà été citées](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/liaisons-et-enchainements). Il n'existe pas de règle en ce qui concerne les liaisons consécutives, après avoir pris en compte les liaisons obligatoires et interdites, on se sert de son bon sens et de l'effet qu'on veut produire selon la situation dans laquelle on se trouve.
Personnellement la suite de mots citée dans la question ne me pose pas de problème, si je devais déclamer le texte je ferais les deux liaisons : *mais͡ ils͡ étaient devenus*. Par contre en conversation courante je ne ferais que la liaison obligatoire : *ils ne sont pas venus mais ils͡  étaient pourtant invités*.

Ce qui est sûr c'est qu'il peut y avoir des cas plus complexes de réitération du son [Z] et le risque de cacophonie n'est jamais loin. Je ne suis pas spécialiste, alors je me contente de citer [Bernard Laks](https://bernardlaks.com/), linguiste, spécialiste de phonologie du français et qui a travaillé sur les liaisons.

> Ce sont enfin des tendances eurythmiques et les dangers d'une cacophonie qui limitent le nombre de liaisons successives possibles. Ainsi, N*ous donnerons͡ aux pauvres* présente une liaison variable sans difficultés, de même *aux͡ uns͡ et aux͡ autres* avec pourtant trois liaisons successives. Mais, *nous donnerons͡ aux͡ hommes* avec deux liaisons consécutives s'avère difficile à cause du [zozm], quant à *nous donnerons͡  aux͡ uns͡ et aux͡ autres* avec toutes les liaisons, cela exige un tempo et une scansion particulièrement lente, laquelle ne parvient qu'à rendre difficilement possible *nous͡ offrirons͡ aux͡ hommes͡ honnêtes͡ affamés͡ et transis*. En diction rapide le zozotement est garanti. C'est ce style par trop liaisonant qui est, fort à propos, raillé par le bon sens populaire : *vous ici quel zazard je vous croyais zo zoo* !
> (*Phonologie et construction syntaxique : la liaison, un test de cohésion et de ﬁgement syntaxique*, in Linx, Revue des linguistes de l'université Paris X Nanterre,  2005). En ligne : https://doi.org/10.4000/linx.274

Answer (score 1):

Comme le dit la référence que vous citez, certaines liaisons sont *plutôt aléatoires*. Ce qui veut dire que parfois nous faisons certaines liaisons, parfois pas, pas seulement en fonction des mots, mais aussi des interlocuteurs, des circonstances, voire des préférences personnelles. Il est parfois possible de faire ou de ne pas faire une liaison sans qu'un auditeur qui parle le Français en tant que langue maternelle ne remarque quoi que ce soit.

Dans le cas de:

> Mais ils étaient devenus plus brumeux ...

À mon avis, le plus naturel est de faire la double liaison dans ce cas. Avec une virgule après le *mais*, il n'y aurait pas de liaison. Si on ne fait pas la liaison, l'oreille imaginerait assez facilement une virgule... suivant la vitesse à laquelle on parle?

Mais je ne suis pas sûr qu'une oreille native détecterait une "faute" dans un cas ou dans l'autre, quel que soit le registre. Plus j'essaie de vérifier ce genre de questions sur des liaisons "ambigües" avec d'autres Français, plus je me heurte à des haussements d'épaules...

Comment: Pas la moindre référence ? La référence c'est vous ? Néanmoins, cette opinion personnelle est  déjà une indication.

Comment: @LPH J'offre une donnée - pas une "opinion" - informée par ma pratique quotidienne de la langue (et non régionale), qui n'a rien de spécial et qui donc représente une pratique courante. Pas besoin d'ajouter de "référence".

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer
« Links to external resources are encouraged »

Comment: Non, « encourager » ne dit pas cela, mais autant que possible on préfère que les affirmations reposent sur des références ; une des raisons pour cela c'est que les références apportent souvent des précisions ; une autre c'est qu'elles sont le produit de nombreuses vérifications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146229/discussion-between-lph-and-frank).

Comment: @LPH 1- Il ne suffit pas d'être un écrit en ligne pour être une référence, n'importe qui peut dire ce qu'il veut sur la toile, faut être expert soi même pour démêler le vrai du faux. 2- Dans un domaine vivant et en constante évolution comme la langue, parlée et écrite, les références ne peuvent être qu'éphémères. On ne parle plus le français comme il y a 30 ans, et quand j'écoute des enregistrements des années 20 j'entends encore autre chose.

Comment: Pour ce qui est de la langue orale la meilleure référence est celle donnée par ceux qui la parlent au quotidien, en leur faisant confiance sur le fait qu'ils parlent une langue que le système scolaire français juge comme correcte. À chacun de voir comment il accorde sa confiance.

Comment: @None Il existe sur la Toile de nombreux professionnels de la langue à qui l'on peut faire confiance (des professeurs)  (Français Facile, Parlez-vous French, Grammaire pour étudiants finnophones, TLFi, Wiktionnaire, Le Larousse, Le Robert, et de nombreux autres), et ils sont faciles à reconnaitre ; un enfant vous dirait que ce sont des références sérieuses. Il ne faut pas exagérer. Quelques brebis galeuses ne font pas un mauvais troupeau. De plus, la langue parlée ne leur est pas étrangère et ils sont capables de fournir beaucoup d'information là-dessus.

Comment: @LPH Ai-je dit le contaire ? Non. Mon propos veut dire qu'un locuteur natif comme Frank (je pense du moins qu'il est locuteur natif du français) est tout autant une référence sur le français parlé que d'autres. Je soutiens son « pas besoin d'ajouter de référence ». Surtout quand dès le départ on sait qu'il n'y a pas de règle et que c'est une question de pratique (et pour moi de situation). *Les langues ne sont nées d’elles-mêmes en façon d’herbes, racines et arbres, [...] mais toute leur vertu est née au monde du vouloir et arbitre des mortels*. (Du Bellay)

Comment: @none Néanmoins, toutes vos contributions reposent sur un nombre substantiel de références de toutes sortes.

Answer (score 1):

Il existe un principe que la liaison « se fait à l'intérieur d'un *mot phonétique*, c'est-à-dire d'un ensemble contenant un seul accent tonique » (LBU14 § 43). Je n'ai jamais vraiment compris cette [notion](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_tonique) donc je ne peux savoir si c'est relié, mais je trouve que le son de la liaison (z) augmente la portée sonore de la coordination et interfère avec la compréhension de l'unité pronom/verbe qui suit et je trouve cette double liaison inusitée. J'entends une espèce de « hésitait » incomplet et ça me dérange. Ma réponse est certainement aléatoire.

Answer (score -2):

Il ne m'est pas possible d'accéder à une information spécifique concernant cette question, mais des indications suffisamment explicites que j'ai finalement découvertes montreraient que cette combinaison particulière est une contre-indication à la pratique de faire deux liaisons.

> [JM Kalmbach, liaisons](http://research.jyu.fi/phonfr/20a.html#2)
> Mais on fait pas la liaison quand **assez** est complément du verbe
>
> - J’ai assez//attendu, on en sait assez // à ce sujet.
>
> […] on évite de la faire après **pas‿assez** (pour éviter les deux /z/ de liaison)
>
> - Ce n’est pas‿assez // explicite.

Dans ce cas concernant « assez » c'est la seconde liaison qui est éliminée, peut-être plus ou moins arbitrairement, et là encore il faudrait des précisions, mais dans le cas du PO, puisque la liaison après « mais » paraitrait être la plus faible, c'est celle-ci qu'il semblerait falloir  éliminer si on pense qu'il y a raison d'être cohérent avec le principe qui peut être lu dans la grammaire de J. M. Kalmbach.

Comment: Au moins pour les apprenants finnophones !